# Proving that there exists a local minimum between two local maximums of a continuous function

Tags: real-analysis, functions

Suppose f is a continuous function that has local maximums at points $x_{1}$ and $x_{2}$. How do I prove that there is a third point between these two points which is a local minimum of f? Need some help thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: Assume that there does not exist a local minimum in $(x_{1},x_{2})$ (assuming that $x_{1}<x_{2}$). Then inf{$f(x)|x∊[x_{1},x_{2}$]}=$f(x_{1})$ or $f(x_{2})$.
Now assume inf{$f(x)|x∊[x_{1},x_{2}$]}=$f(x_{1})$. Then $f(x)$≥$f(x_{1})$ when x∊[$x_{1},x_{2}$]. Also there exists $δ>0$ such that $f(x_{1})$∊$[x_{1},x_{1}+δ]$.
Then we get that $f(x)$=$f(x_{1})$. This is a contradiction. DO the same for $f(x_{2})$.